# Application of Kirchhoff's rule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I came across a problem, in which I was supposed to find the power through the 10-ohm resistor, the one at the top (I forgot to label it). I applied Kirchhoff's loop rule and found the current flowing through the 10-ohm resistor as 2 A. The current through the 5-ohm resistor (rightmost) also came out to be 2 A. The solution also proceeded in the same way.

But, I wonder if a current would even pass through the 5-ohm resistor because ignoring it will also give me the same answer. The battery is ideal, hence without resistance. So, I think no current should flow through the resistor and it should be as good as absent. But which view is correct?

By the way, I tried using Thevenin method, but there I seem to be getting the answer only if I ignore it.

[image]

Comment: There is no 10 ohm resistor in your schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current in the rightmost 5 Ohm resistor has no influence on the current in the 10 Ohm resistor and vice versa because the voltage across the 5 Ohm resistor is fixed at 10 volts. It can therefore be ignored.

Comment: Just for clarification: if I use the Thevenin theorem, should I consider the right-most resistor? I think not, but I do not know why.

Comment: @Krishna You remove it. The Thevenin equivalent voltage between two terminals is the open circuit voltage between the terminals. If the two terminals are across the 10 volt battery that means the 5 Ohm resistor has to be removed. Obviously the open circuit voltage has to be 10 volts. The Thevenin resistance is the resistance between the terminals with all ideal voltage sources short-circuited. That gives zero equivalent resistance between the terminals. The Thevenin equivalent circuit is simply an ideal 10 volt battery with no resistance, which should be obvious from the get go.